# My implementation of Karatsuba Multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have recently implemented [Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) in C++ for my Algorithms course. It is a very sloppy implementation because I ran out of time, yet criticism would be appreciated. I probably could have implemented it using bit manipulation but I decided to instead use strings, and I could have also probably put the methods in a class.

The Karatsuba method is called `multiply()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string; using std::vector;

const string str_add(const string &x_const, const string &y_const);

string str_mult(const string &x, const string &y) {
  //std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
  auto iter1 = x.rbegin();

  vector<string> num; // Holds all the numbers before the addition step is done
  unsigned padding_count = 0; // Counts how many zeros must be added to the end of the number

  unsigned carry = 0;
  string temp; // Holds string before it is appended to vector

  for (; iter1 != x.rend(); ++iter1) {
    auto iter2 = y.rbegin();
    temp.clear();
    for (; iter2 != y.rend(); ++iter2) {
      unsigned product = (*iter1-'0') * (*iter2-'0') + carry;
      if (product > 9) {
        unsigned temporary = product;
        product %= 10;
        carry = (temporary - product) / 10;
      }
      else
        carry = 0;
      temp.insert(0, 1, (product + '0'));
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
      temp.insert(0, 1, (carry + '0'));
      carry = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < padding_count; ++i)
      temp += '0';
    num.push_back(temp);
    ++padding_count;
  }
  /*temp.clear();
  if (carry > 0)
    temp.insert(0, 1, (carry + '0'));
  for (int i = 0; i < padding_count; ++i)
    temp += '0';
  num.push_back(temp);*/

  string str_product;
  for (auto iter = num.begin(); iter != num.end(); ++iter) {
    //std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    str_product = str_add(*iter, str_product);
  }

  for (auto iter = str_product.begin(); iter != str_product.end()-1; ++iter) {
    if (*iter == '0') {
      str_product.erase(iter);
      --iter;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
  return str_product;
}

void balance_str(string &x, string &y) {
  if (x.length() < y.length()) // If x is shorter than y pad it with zeros
    x.insert(0, y.length() - x.length(), '0');
  if (x.length() > y.length()) // If y is shorter than x pad it with zeros
    y.insert(0, x.length() - y.length(), '0');
}

const string str_add(const string &x_const, const string &y_const) {
  string x = x_const; // Create copies
  string y = y_const; // of the arguments
  //std::cout << "Add: " << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
  balance_str(x, y); // Pad the strings with zeros if necessary

  auto iter1 = x.rbegin(); // Initialise iterators
  auto iter2 = y.rbegin(); // for the loops
  unsigned carry = 0; // The carry on digit

  string str_sum; // The string to be returned

  for (; iter1 != x.rend() && iter2 != y.rend(); ++iter1, ++iter2) {
    unsigned sum = (*iter1-'0') + (*iter2-'0') + carry; // Find out the sum of string digits
    if (sum > 9) { // If greater than 9 carry however many are required
      carry = 1;
      sum -= 10;
    }
    else // Else reset the carry counter
      carry = 0;
    str_sum.insert(0, 1, (sum + '0'));
  }
  str_sum.insert(0, 1, (carry + '0'));

  for (auto iter = str_sum.begin(); iter != str_sum.end()-1; ++iter) {
    if (*iter == '0') {
      str_sum.erase(iter);
      --iter;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
  //std::cout << str_sum << std::endl;

  return str_sum;
}

const string str_subtract(const string &x_const, const string &y_const) {
  string x = x_const; // Create copies
  string y = y_const; // of the arguments
  balance_str(x,y); // Pad the string with zeros if necessary
  auto iter1 = x.rbegin(); // Initialise iterators
  auto iter2 = y.rbegin(); // for the loops
  int carry = 0; // The carry on digit

  //std::cout << "In add : " << std::flush;
  string str_diff; // The string to be returned

  for (; iter1 != x.rend() && iter2 != y.rend(); ++iter1, ++iter2) {
    int diff = (*iter1-'0') - (*iter2-'0') - carry; // Find out the sum of the string digits
    if (diff < 0) { // If greater than 9 carry however many required
      carry = 1;
      diff = 10+diff;
    }
    else // Else reset the carry counter
      carry = 0;
    str_diff.insert(0, 1, (diff + '0'));
  }

  //std::cout << "Out of add" << std::endl;

  for (auto iter = str_diff.begin(); iter != str_diff.end()-1; ++iter) {
    if (*iter == '0') {
      str_diff.erase(iter);
      --iter;
    }
    else
      break;
  }
  return str_diff;
}

string multiply(const string &x, const string &y) {
  //std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n' << std::endl;
  if (x.length() < 2 || y.length() < 2) // Base case
    return str_mult(x, y);
  unsigned n = ((x.length() >= y.length()) ? x.length() : y.length())/2; // Init n
  string p = "10"; // Power
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) // Init power
    p += '0';
  string a, b, c, d;
  for (auto iter = x.begin(); iter != x.begin() + x.length()/2; ++iter) // Split x into a
    a += *iter;
  for (auto iter = x.begin() + x.length()/2; iter != x.end(); ++iter) // and into b
    b += *iter;
  for (auto iter = y.begin(); iter != y.begin() + y.length()/2; ++iter) // Split y into c
    c += *iter;
  for (auto iter = y.begin() + y.length()/2; iter != y.end(); ++iter) // and into d
    d += *iter;

  //std::cout << "A: " << a << " B: " << b << "\nC: " << c << " D: " << d << std::endl;
  //std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;

  //std::cout << "P: " << p << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "N: " << n << std::endl;

  string ac = multiply(a, c); // Init ac through recursion
  string bd = multiply(b, d); // Init bd through recursion
  string abcd = str_subtract(str_subtract(multiply(str_add(a,b), str_add(c,d)), ac), bd);
  // Init abcd through recursion

  return str_add(str_mult(str_add(str_mult(ac,p), abcd),p),bd);
}



int main () {
  string x, y;
  std::cin >> x >> y;
  std::cout << '\n' << multiply(x, y) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << str_mult(x, y) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << str_add(x,y) << std::endl;
  //std::cout << str_subtract(x, y) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explicitly state the goal the code presented is to achieve. (The comments don't tell (yet)…)

Comment: This still has commented out debugging code in it. It's not ready for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  for (auto iter = x.begin(); iter != x.begin() + x.length()/2; ++iter) // Split x into a
    a += *iter;
  for (auto iter = x.begin() + x.length()/2; iter != x.end(); ++iter) // and into b
    b += *iter;
  for (auto iter = y.begin(); iter != y.begin() + y.length()/2; ++iter) // Split y into c
    c += *iter;
  for (auto iter = y.begin() + y.length()/2; iter != y.end(); ++iter) // and into d
    d += *iter;
```

you're splitting the strings by index using iterators, then concatenating each character into the result.  This seems very expensive.  You would probably get better performance by using string.substr to get the different strings you need:

```
int halfPt = x.length() / 2;
a = x.substr(0, halfPt);
b = x.substr(halfPt);
halfPt = y.length() / 2;
c = y.substr(0, halfPt);
d = y.substr(halfPt);
```

You seem to be using iterators a lot to iterate through the strings.  I would suggest that any time you have the option to use an index instead of an iterator, you'll find it not only easier to use, but also quicker.